# array output structure

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
<?php 
    $c = count($rank); // 5

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $labels [] = array("value" =>$i, "text" => $i);
    }

?>

output: `[{"value":1,"text":1},{"value":2,"text":2},{"value":3,"text":3},{"value":4,"text":4},{"value":5,"text":5}]`
```

But what I need is:

```
[{"value":5,"text":1},{"value":4,"text":2},{"value":3,"text":3},{"value":2,"text":4},{"value":1,"text":5}]
```

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll describe my line of thinking.

What is the pattern in the sequence `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`? Quite clearly, I decrease by one each time. I already know that `$i` increases by one each time, because that is how we wrote our for loop. My goal and what is available with `$i` is fairly close, so is there any way I can use `$i`?

Indeed there is. Instead of saying the sequence `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` decreases by one each time, I can say that the sequence *increases* in its distance from 5 by one each time. That is, the sequence is equivalent to `5 - 0, 5 - 1, 5 - 2, 5 - 3, 5 - 4`. Notice that this lines up perfectly with `$i`. Therefore, our solution can be the following:

```
<?php 
$c = count($rank); // 5

for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
      $labels [] = array("value" =>($c - $i), "text" => $i);
}
```

This takes a bit of intuition to see, and if you are in a similar situation and cannot figure out the pattern, you can always introduce a new variable.

```
<?php 
$c = count($rank); // 5


for ($decreasing = $c, $i = 0; $i < $c; $i++, --$decreasing) {
      $labels [] = array("value" =>$decreasing, "text" => $i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just wanting the value to decrement by one every time? If so subtract the iterator count from the total count:

```
<?php 
    $c = count($rank); // 5

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $labels [] = array("value" =>($c - $i), "text" => $i);
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$c = count($rank); // 5
$j = $c;
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $labels [] = array("value" =>$j, "text" => $i);
    $j --;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$labels [] = array("value" => ($c - $i), "text" => ($i + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show won't produce that array because `$i` iterates over 0...4 whereas the values in your array are 1...5. But it appears that what you need to do is to change the statement inside the `for` loop to

```
$c = count($rank); // 5

for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
  $labels[] = array("value" =>5-$i, "text" => $i+1);
}
```

or perhaps using `array_map`

```
$c = count($rank); // 5
$labels = array_map(function ($n) {
  return array("value" => 6-$n, "text" => $n);
}, range(1, $c));
```